# How to find a string that is (and isn't) wrapped around some pattern in Python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, tags

Let's say, I have the following string (yes it is in string format).

```
body = 'start [caption] <a>A Images</a> [/caption] <a> Another Image </a> end'
```

- Case 1, When I find `<a>` surrounded by `[caption] [/caption]` I want to do something and
- Case 2, When I find `<a>` **without** being wrapped by `[caption] [/caption]` I want to do something *else*.

I am already able to do the first one by:

```
captionPattern = r'\[caption.*?/caption\]'
```

Now, I want to do the same, but extracting `<a>` that is not wrapped by `[caption] [/caption]`

I can write code to simply match `<a>...</a>` but this would match all the `<a>...</a>` including those in Case 1.

Comment: Try looking into `beautifulsoup` library

Comment: If present, will the `[caption]` always be right next to the `<a>` tags?

Comment: @Akaisteph7, yes, like this `[caption id="attachment_12345" align="aligncenter" width="123"]<a href=...`

Comment: @MdShihabJamil sorry for the late answer. see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
body = 'start [caption] <a>A Images</a> [/caption] <a> Another Image </a> end'
captionPattern = "(\[caption.*?/caption\])|(<a>.*?</a>)"
results = re.findall(captionPattern, body)

with_caption = [elem for elem in results[0] if elem]
without_caption = [elem for elem in results[1] if elem]
print(with_caption)
print(without_caption)
```

Output:

```
['[caption] <a>A Images</a> [/caption]']
['<a> Another Image </a>']
```